# Delphi 10.4.2 CE doesn't stop on set breakpoints on Samsung A02s

Tags: android, debugging, delphi

Title pretty much says it all.  I have a barebones app, consisting of a header-footer form, with a TLabel in the header.  In the form.create event handler, I change the text to 'Test Program #2'.  I then set a breakpoint on the line where the text is changed and deploy/run the app in debug mode.  Developer options are enabled on the phone, as is USB debugging.  The app runs as expected, with the changed text being displayed, except that the breakpoint is never triggered. I checked to ensure that a conditional was not set, it is not. I have also double checked that debug configuration is selected and that development configuration is set in the Android Target config as well. I have googled the issue, no joy, just links to the same 3 articles over and over.  The A02s is running Android version 12 as OS.

What I've tried:  rebooting phone, rebooting computer, updating ADB drivers, invalidating debug authorizations on phone

Comment: Does Delphi actually switch into debug layout while application is running on your device? If not it is possible hat Delphi can't communicate properly with PAServer that is used for remote debugging of any mobile or Win64 bit application. This could be caused by your computers firewall since Delphi and PAServec communicate with each other through a network connection.

Comment: @SilverWarior; Apologies for taking so long to get back to you on this.  Yes, it switches to debug layout.  I also have recently tried the new Delphi 11 CE, as my phone is running Android 12, and thought it might have to do with an incompatibility between Andy 12 and Delphi 10.4, but the same behavior is happening.  The Breakpoint is still greened out, but the code is executed.  I tried moving the code to a different event handler, no joy there either. I have tried deleting the generated .dcu as well.